# How to round up a fraction on java?

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

So I'm trying to write a method on java that takes as input two floats that represent two area.
It returns the quotient of the division of area1 by area2 rounded up as an integer.
Here's my code :

```
public class PizzaClal {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.println(round_up(15.0, 6.0));
    }

    static int round_up(double area1, double area2) {
        double diff1 = area1 / area2;
        double diff2 = area2 / area1;

        if (area2 > area1  && diff2 > (int) diff2)  {
            return (int) (diff2) + 1;
        }if (area1 > area2 && diff1 > (int) diff1) {
            return (int) (diff1) + 1;
        } else{
            return (int) (diff1);
        }
    }
}
```

It is suppose to return 3 but it return 67. I'm new in java and I only know Python so I don't really understand where's my error. can anyone help me please?

Comment: You code gives me `3`

Answer (score 1):

[Math.ceil](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double)) will round up, and sounds like what you want (assuming `area1` and `area2` are both greater than 0).

```
public class PizzaClal {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.println(round_up(15.0, 6.0));
    }

    static int round_up(double area1, double area2) {
        if (area1 > area2) {
            return Math.ceil(area1 / area2);
        } else {
            return Math.ceil(area2 / area1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can greatly simplify your code if you basically just want to return the ceiling of a division result. One trick is to use the `modulus` operator `%`, which returns the *remainder of division*, which is particularly useful here. If the remainder of `a / b` is non-zero, then `b` does not divide `a` evenly. Just adding `1` to the integer division result will produce a "ceiling" result. You can simply cast `(area1 / area2)` to an integer to acquire the integer division result.

```
static int round_up(double area1, double area2) {
    int result = (int) (area1 / area2);
    if (area1 % area2 != 0) {
        result++;
    }
    return result;
}
```